# AS3 GESTURE_SWIPE with N-Trig powered touch screens

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, touchscreen, gestures

I'm currently developing a prototype using AS3 and trying out some touchscreen gestures.

I'm compiling using AIR 2.0 and currently have GESTURE_ZOOM and GESTURE_ROTATE working but for some reason GESTURE_SWIPE is giving me a few headaches. I know It's possible as I've seen it working here, using the same laptop (DELL LATITUDE XT2 & N-TRIG) as I'm testing on.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6u8ynaCPIoY

Here is my code.

```
stage.addEventListener(TransformGestureEvent.GESTURE_SWIPE, onStageSwipe);
function onStageSwipe(e:TransformGestureEvent):void
{
  if (e.offsetX == 1)
  {
    //User swiped towards right
    swipe.text = "swipped right";
  }
  if (e.offsetX == -1)
  {
    //User swiped towards left
    swipe.text = "swipped left";
  }
}
```

I've also tried this using a `Movieclip` rather than the stage and still no use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question is you can't. GESTURE_SWIPE isn't a valid command on the XT2.